# Messages leak out from Block

Tags: bugs, scoping, message-coding

**Bug introduced in 8.0 or earlier and fixed in 10.1**

---

When assigning message to a symbol localized by `Block`, I would expect that this message is not accessible outside of `Block`, but I observe different behavior:

```
ClearAll[x]
Block[{x}, x::test1 = "message1"];
x::test1
(* "message1" *)
```

Message was assigned to `x` globally regardless of `x` being localized.

It also happens with direct assignment to `Messages`:

```
ClearAll[x]
Block[{x}, Messages[x] = {HoldPattern[x::test2] :> "message2"}];
x::test2
(* "message2" *)
```

I get this behavior in all versions I have available:  8.0.0, 9.0.1 and 10.0.0 on Linux.

Is this a bug?

Comment: I think this happens because `MessageName` has certain auto-stringification step, which allows the second argument of MessageName to be a symbol. When the definition is constructed, it is auto-stringified, but then still attached to the symbol. From the point of view of what `Block` is supposed to do, this can be probably considered a bug.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin But it also happens when directly assigning to `Messages` list. Is `MessageName` involved also in this kind of assignment?

Comment: I think it has to. May be not `MessageName` specifically, but I think that the underlying mechanism used to attach message(s) to symbol(s) should be the same in both cases. And it is this mechanism whose interaction with `Block` looks problematic.

Comment: @Leonid Are you comfortable adding the `bugs` tag to this one?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think so. I just did.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has been fixed in **10.1** (windows)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

[image: Mathematica graphics]

code

```
ClearAll[x]
Block[{x}, x::test1 = "message1"];
x::test1

ClearAll[x]
Block[{x}, Messages[x] = {HoldPattern[x::test2] :> "message2"}];
x::test2

Block[{x}, x /: x::foo = "bar"; Message[x::foo]];
Messages[x]
```

Answer (score 8):

My initial answer was simply wrong.  I now think this *is* a bug.  Although a message may be expressly attached to the Symbol `x` using [`TagSet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagSet.html) it is still not localized.  (`TagSet` is superfluous but it helps make the point.)

```
Block[{x}, x /: x::foo = "bar"; Message[x::foo]];

Messages[x]
```

> During evaluation of In[]:= x::foo: bar
>
> ```
> {HoldPattern[x::foo] :> "bar"}
> ```

In fact attempting to attach the rule to `MessageName` yields this:

```
MessageName /: x::foo = "bar";
```

> MessageName::tag: Rule for MessageName of x::foo can only be attached to x. >>

Comment: But `Subscript` has no "automagic" defined like `MessageName`. Assigning to `MessageName` really assigns to symbols `Messages` and it also happens when assigning directly to `Messages` which I expected to behave like `DownValues` etc.

Comment: @jkuczm Nevertheless the underlying cause may be the same, in that the definition is not attached to the Symbol `x`.  I am working on this now.  Sorry for the premature answer.

Comment: I thought it should assign to `x`. ``Language`ExtendedDefinition[x]`` gives among others `Messages` list with message assigned inside `Block`.

Comment: @jkuczm Good point.  Answer rewritten.