# $MessageList inside and outside Block[]

Tags: programming, evaluation, system

Why does

```
1/0
$MessageList
```

> ```
> ComplexInfinity
> ```

whereas

```
Block[{},
1/0;
$MessageList
]
```

> ```
> Power::infy
> ```

?

At  first sight I supposed that this disparity could be related to an answer I got here [subtleties about variable shadowing in Block[]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78102/subtleties-about-variable-shadowing-in-block)
"*Symbols are created at the instant that they are read -- not when they are evaluated.*". But, may be, this time we are facing a totally different problem because `$MessageList` exists rigth before `Block[]` is read.

Have I missed some point explained in   [Messages leak out from Block](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/73458/messages-leak-out-from-block) ?

Thanks once more !!

Comment: Not sure what do you expect, Block has nothing to do with this, try `1/
  0; $MessageList`.Or have I missed something?

Comment: I expect the same message (Power::infy or ComplexInfinity) in both situations.

Comment: You should not, you have `CompoundExpression` in `Block` and two separate lines in first code area. `$MessageList` remembers only current execution line

Answer (score 5):

> `$MessageList` is a global variable that gives a list of the names of messages generated **during the evaluation of the current input line**.

The confusion is probably due to the wording, in reality *Wolfram System* reads **expression by expression but not less than one line**. See [**How parsing works, more or less**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119187/5478).

Those are two separate inputs

```
1/0
$MessageList
```

while this is one input, the first line is not a full expression, MMA has to read more:

```
Block[{},
  1/0;
  $MessageList
]
```