# Where does a package have to be loaded?

Tags: evaluation, packages, scoping, contexts

I'm trying to solve a very tricky issue in my function. The function needs the `` NDSolve`FEM` `` framework.

Here is a minimal example:

```
Quit[]
```

```
GetBoundaryMesh[obj_] := Module[{bmesh},
   Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
   bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh @ obj;
   MeshPrimitives[MeshRegion @ bmesh, 1]
]
```

```
GetBoundaryMesh[Disk[]]
```

> ```
>  MeshPrimitives[MeshRegion[Global`ToBoundaryMesh[Disk[{0,0}]]],1]
> ```

**Something went wrong,** I was expecting a list of `Lines` which I can get by executing this code manually:

```
Quit[]
```

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh @ obj;
MeshPrimitives[MeshRegion @ bmesh, 1]
```

> ```
> {Line[{{1.,0.},{0.991575,0.129537}}],<<46>>,Line[{{<<19>>,-<<20>>},{<<1>>}}]}
> ```

To me it seems like it isn't importing the `` NDSolve`FEM `` package correctly, but that's just my best guess.

---

Loose thoughts

When I close MMa and open my notebook again, if I do `$Packages`, `` FEM`NDSolve `` isn't there (as expected):

```
{"GetFEKernelInit`", "StreamingLoader`", "IconizeLoader`", \
"CloudObjectLoader`", "ResourceLocator`", "PacletManager`", \
"System`", "Global`"}
```

Even after I evaluate the cell that holds all my functions, it's still not in `$Packages`. At this point, if I run my function, it gives the same problem, because apparently it has not loaded the package (despite it being the first line in the function it runs...?).

*However,* after I run the function once (and it gives its error), if I check `$Packages`, it *is there!* So it seems like it *is* loading it, but somehow the function isn't seeing that in time when it's called..?

Okay, I managed to solve the problem kind of by explicitly calling `ToBoundaryMesh` this way:

```
NDSolve`FEM`ToBoundaryMesh@ashape;
```

That seems to work on the first try, but why didn't it work without explicitly calling it? Why isn't it in the `$Packages` list for the function once `Needs[]` is called?

I was reading [here about packages and context](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ContextsAndPackages.html) but I didn't really see the answer.

Comment: To rephrase what @Kuba said, the code of your  `GetBoundaryMesh` is parsed before the call to `Needs`, and therefore the symbol `ToBoundaryMesh` is not found anywhere on the `$ContextPath` and is considered a new symbol. So, it is created in the current working context (``"Global`"`` in this case). If you call `Needs` before defining `GetBoundaryMesh`, then by the time the code of `GetBoundaryMesh` is parsed, the context  ``NDSolve`FEM` `` is already on the `$ContextPath`. So, in this case, the symbol is found there and bound to the right one.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin thank you both. I think I almost get it. But why, when the function is called, doesn't it know that it belongs to NDSolve`FEM`? It seems like that would make the most sense, because it has *some* definition for NDSolve`FEM` at that point, but no definition in Global. Anyway, I think my solution (calling it explicitly) should work fine, right?

Comment: @YungHummmma I have a more detailed explanation of package mechanics [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29325/81) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135510/define-private-function-in-a-mathematica-package/5135924#5135924). Basically, when the loader sees a new symbol, it searches for it in all packages currently on the `$ContextPath`. If no symbol with this name is found there, the symbol is created in the current context. So, you *have to* load your dependencies *before* your code is parsed, so that they are added to the `$ContextPath`. And yes, your solution will work.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin thanks, seems good then. If you or kuba can make an answer I can choose that as an answer then. Thank you both!

Comment: I will leave it for @Kuba to decide. If he decides not to post,   I will convert my comments into one, just so that the question won't be left as unanswered.

Comment: If you load the package this way, then refer to the symbol names from the pckage with their fully qualified name, i.e. ``NDSolve`FEM`ToBoundaryMesh`` instead of `ToBoundaryMesh`.

Comment: @Szabolcs that's what I ended up doing and it works great, thank you :)

Comment: @YungHummmma "But why, when the function is called, doesn't it know that it belongs to NDSolveFEM?"  `DeclarePackage` enables it to know this belonging as well as automatically loading the relevant (declared) package.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### tl;dr

You need to call `Needs` before `GetBoundaryMesh` definition so it can be parsed (found in correct context) correctly or you have to use the full name of `ToBoundaryMesh`.

---

### Relevant part of documentation

from [SettingUpWolframLanguagePackages](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SettingUpWolframLanguagePackages.html)

> Executing a function like `Begin` which manipulates contexts changes the way that the Wolfram Language interprets names you type in. However, you should realize that the change is effective only in subsequent expressions that you type in. **The point is that the Wolfram Language always reads in a complete input expression, and interprets the names in it, before it executes any part of the expression**. As a result, **by the time `Begin` is executed in a particular expression, the names in the expression have already been interpreted**, and it is too late for `Begin` to have an effect.
>
> The fact that context manipulation functions do not have an effect until the next complete expression is read in means that you must be sure to give those functions as separate expressions, typically on separate lines, when you write Wolfram Language packages.

---

### How parsing works, more or less

1. Input is **read**

   Wolfram system *reads expression by expression* (keep in mind that `a; b;` in one line is a `CompundExpression`. (alternatively one can say: *line by line but not less than expression*, e.g. `Hold[` is not full expression so more than one line will be read).
2. Expression is **parsed**

   e.g. `Identity[mySymbol]` -> `` System`Identity[Global`mySymbol] ``
3. Expression is **evaluated**

   `` System`Identity[Global`mySymbol] `` -> `` Global`mySymbol `` (or its OwnValue if there is any)

**!!! This sequence of steps (so parsing too) can also be triggered during evaluation** by functions which are converting strings, streams or boxes to expressions, e.g. `Get`, `ToExpression`, `Read` etc. Take a look at example 2.

---

#### Example 1

Assuming `MySymbol` is a new symbol.

With `()` it is a `CompoundExpression` so it's read as a whole:

```
(
 BeginPackage["Test`"];
 MySymbol;
 EndPackage[];
)
```

It is parsed to

```
System`CompoundExpression[
    System`BeginPackage["Test`"], 
    Global`MySymbol,  
    System`EndPackage[], 
    System`Null
]
```

It is `` Global` ``  because `BeginPackage` wasn't evaluated yet. (Often it will be `` Global` ``  but in general it is `$Context` more about: [**2. How symbol lookup actually works**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/43629/5478)

In package (.m), `Get` reads line by line (there are no ()s) and `MySymbol` is parsed separately after already evaluated `BeginPackage` - ergo it will be created in `` Test` ``  context.

#### Example 2

Quit the kernel first, we want to forget about `MySymbol`.

```
(
 BeginPackage["Test`"];
 ToExpression["MySymbol"];
 EndPackage[];
)
```

Now we get:

```
System`CompoundExpression[
    System`BeginPackage["Test`"],    (*1*)
    System`ToExpression["MySymbol"], (*2*)
    System`EndPackage[],             (*3*)
    System`Null
]
```

Which is evaluated:

- `(*1*)` changes current `$Context` to `` Test` ``
- `(*2*)` `ToExpression` parses and evaluates `"MySymbol"` **but in new `$Context`!**(**1**)
- `(*3*)` `$Context` switched back to `` Global` ``

---

> [...] What I meant is that you can't use `Begin` and `End` inside of `Initialization` without forcing a separate parse stage to begin, as would happen with `Get` or `ToExpression`. Yes, you should be able to use `Begin/End` outside of `CreatePalette`, but **only if they are on separate lines of input**. I.e., **they can't be a part of a `CompoundExpression`** or other expression which contains the `CreatePalette` command. This means terminating all operators and placing a newline in the input cell, or putting the `Begin/End` in totally different cells.
>
> – John Fultz Feb 6 '12 at 15:19

---

### Confession

My old comment is partially incorrect

> `$Context or $ContextPath` changes (done by `Get/Needs/BeginPackage` and friends) are reflected after/between evaluations[...]

Changes of `$Context/$ContextPath` are done immediately but it can't affect already parsed expression.

---

[1] [palettes with non-trivial functionality](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/167/what-are-the-most-common-usual-ways-to-make-palettes-with-non-trivial-function/1113#comment3499_1113)

[2] [How symbol lookup actually works](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/43629/5478)

[3] [FullForm with context for each symbol?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119924/5478)