# How does Context work?

Tags: contexts, localization

I thought when we type a symbol without specifying its `Context`, it will search all the `Context` in `$ContextPath` for existing symbol.

But in `Module`/`Block`, or even `CompoundExpression`, all the symbols will be converted to `Global` Context regardless of the content of `$ContextPath`.

Unfortunately, I didn't find any information in the documentation explaining this behavior.Is it a feature? What is purpose of this design?

Here is my example:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Code Here:

```
AppendTo[$ContextPath, "w`"];
w`ww = 1;
Context[ww]
```

---

Similar behaviour can be observed as follows:

```
Quiet@Remove["A`x", "B`x", "Global`x"];
{A`x, B`x} = {"a", "b"};
$Context = "A`";
Print@x;
$Context = "B`";
Print@x;
$Context = "Global`";
```

gives `a, b`, but

```
(
 Quiet@Remove["A`x", "B`x", "Global`x"];
 {A`x, B`x} = {"a", "b"};
 $Context = "A`";
 Print@x;
 $Context = "B`";
 Print@x;
 $Context = "Global`";
 )
```

gives `Removed[x]` twice.

Comment: Take a look here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/115849/5478

Comment: `$ContextPath` affects *parsing*, not evaluation.  Because of the parentheses, ``(AppendTo[$ContextPath, "w`"]; w`ww = 1; Context[ww])`` is parsed in its entirety first, and evaluation begins only afterwards.  Before the first part of this is evaluated, `$ContextPath` isn't changed yet.

Comment: @Szabolcs so you mean there is a parsing step that adds `Context` to symbols first, which is not in http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Evaluation.html. Is the parsing step executed before the whole evaluation?

Comment: @Szabolcs would you mind telling me how you got this information? Is it from the docs or some smart investigation?

Comment: "Parsing" means converting the *text* that you entered into an actual expression. When Mathematica reads `x`, it immediately needs to decide whether this refers to ``a`x`` or ``b`x`` or something else.  Evaluation can only start after a full expression is read it.  When you add parentheses, you make those separate lines into a single expression.

Comment: Well, it's just a hypothesis, but it's a very reasonable one.  To come up with it, there's no other investigation needed than what you already tried and thinking a bit about how Mathematica could theoretically be implemented.  You can devise additional tests with `ToExpression` to try to falsify this hypothesis and gain more confidence. This behaviour was discussed on this site multiple times, but I was too lazy to find it.  I assumed Kuba's link pointed to one.

Comment: @Szabolcs thanks you very much for sharing this, I will try to investigate more individually in the future

Comment: I added another example illustrating a similar thing.

Comment: @happyfish is my recent answer enough to mark it a duplicate? [Where does a package have to be loaded?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119187/5478)

Comment: @Kuba of course. I really appreciate your detail explanation on this problem.

Comment: @happyfish I'm glad you find it useful. Feedback appreciated, if anything is not clear or could be rephrased for readers benefit just tell me :)

Answer (score 1):

I think every line or statement that you enter into the frontend is parsed separately, so, when you use a CompoundStatement there is only one parsing process, while there is one for each line when you split them.

From tutorial/Contexts we learn that unknown symbols are created in the `$Context` when they are not found in `$ContextPath`. Most likely the lookup for unqualified symbols happens at the parsing stage with the values that `$Context, $ContextPath` have at that time.

I assume that internally, an "unqualified symbol" (one with an empty `Context`) is not even a thing.