# how to do an idiomatic qualified import in WL?

Tags: packages, core-language

I want to import a package in a way that requires me to use the long names for package symbols, just as if I had created the context on the fly.  What is the idiomatic way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if you really want what you said you want. That is because if you load a package, all symbols are already created, just by parsing.

What you can do is to not introduce new contexts on `$ContextPath` which will force you to use long names.

It is mentioned in Leonid's answer in [What are the use cases for different scoping constructs?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/569/5478) but it is probably to broad to mark as a duplicate.

```
Block[{$ContextPath}, Get@"JLink`"]
```

> [image]

About parsing and symbol lookup you can read in

- [How symbol lookup actually works](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/43629/5478)
- [Where does a package have to be loaded?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119187/5478)

---

Your question can be interpreted also in that way:

```
BeginPackage["Test`"];
  random;
Begin["`Private`"];
  random := random = (Pause[1]; 4);
End[];
EndPackage[]
```

Now `random` symbol is also created instantaneously but it will be defined after you call the first time.