# Context inside Do[...]-loop

Tags: packages, contexts, parsing, variable

Consider the following code:

```
Begin["mycontext`"];
myvar = 7;
Print[Context[]];
Print[Context[myvar]];
End[];
```

with the output

> mycontext`
>
> mycontext`

Now consider the same code inside a Do-loop:

```
Do[
Begin["mycontext`"];
myvar = 7;
Print[Context[]];
Print[Context[myvar]];
End[];
, {i,1,2}];
```

which produces the output

> mycontext`
>
> Global`
>
> mycontext`
>
> Global`

What is going on here? Why is myvar considered to be in "Global`"? Even if I force the definition to

```
mycontext`myvar = 7;
```

it will still be considered to be global. How do I use contexts inside loops correctly?

The whole point of doing this is the following:
I have several similar configuration files (that only contain variables) in "./folder1/config.m" and "./folder2/config.m" etc. which I have to apply some manipulations to. My idea is to loop over all folders, use a local context, Get["./folderX/config.m"], write some new values for the variables, and then Save["./folderX/config.m", "mycontext`"].

Example config.m

```
currentfolderstuff = 0;
anotherfolderstuff = 0;
```

What I want to do

```
Do[
(* some sophisticated stuff with many variable names that will pollute my local context *)
a = i^2 + 7^2 + ...;
b = somefunc[i];
Begin["mycontex`"];
Get["./folder"<>ToString[i]<>"/config.m"];
currentfolderstuff = a;
anotherfolderstuff = b;
Save["./folder"<>ToString[i]<>"/newconfig.m", "mycontext`"];
End[];
, {i,1,2}];
```

Comment: [**Where does a package have to be loaded?**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/115849/5478)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where does a package have to be loaded?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/115849/where-does-a-package-have-to-be-loaded)

Comment: I do not full understand your update, and how these config files are related to contexts.  Perhaps a explicit example will help. `Get` is affected by `Begin` because `Get` needs to parse the contents of a file.  Regarding config files: I recommend storing config data as associations instead of *code* (i.e. several assignment lines).

Comment: @Szabolcs: I don't have any influence in designing the config files. They are used in an external MMA program which I am trying to configurate.

Comment: You could use `BeginPackage` instead of `Begin` to ensure that `$ContextPath` only has your context while reading the file (see [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/43629/12)), and explicitly specify the context on `currentfolderstuff`, i.e. write ``mycontext`currentfolderstuff`` in your loop.  I have not tested this, so there might be a little mistake in there somewhere.

Comment: Actually, instead of using `BeginPackage`, just enclose the `Get` in ``Block[{$ContextPath = {"mycontext`", "System`"}, $Context = "mycontext`"}, Get[...]]``.  `BeginPackage` does other things too which you do not want.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Awesome! It's working. But why? How does Block[...] ensure, that "mycontext\`currentfolderstuff" **outside** of Block[...] gets recognized to be not in "Global`" (as opposed to the version without Block[...]).

Comment: @Szabolcs: For clarification: I used "Begin[...]; Block[..., Get[...]]; mycontext\`currentfolderstuff = a; ... End[];" This works. However just using "Block[..., Get[...]; mycontext\`currentfolderstuff = a; ...];" without any Begin statement does also work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`` Begin["mycontext`"] `` affects the parser, not the evaluator.

These are separate expressions:

```
Begin["mycontext`"];
```

```
myvar = 7;
```

```
Print[Context[]];
```

```
Print[Context[myvar]];
```

```
End[];
```

They get parsed and evaluated one by one.  Once `` Begin["mycontext`"]; `` is evaluated, the new context applies to all subsequent lines.

This is a single expression:

```
Do[
Begin["mycontext`"];
myvar = 7;
Print[Context[]];
Print[Context[myvar]];
End[];
, {i,1,2}];
```

It gets parsed as one unit, an evaluation begins only afterwards. `` Begin["mycontext`"]; `` does not get a chance to get evaluated before the parsing of `myvar`.

Comment: Ok, so how do I fix that? How do I force MMA to evaluate Begin[] inside a loop separately?

Comment: @Marcel In most cases trying to do this is a bad idea. `Begin` does not belong in a loop. Can you explain in clear terms why you want to do it?  (Please edit the question instead of explaining in a comment.)

Comment: @Marcel please show a line or two from your config files so that everything is clear. Since the context does not change you can begin it before calling Do and close after.

Comment: @Kuba: Ok, I have done that.